# Disable StartApp SDK auto show ads when activity is visibile

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk, startapp

I was successfully able to add StartApp ads to my project, I only added 1 banner.

My question is, why a full screen ad keeps showing when my activity is visibile? (e.g: I'm inside the app then I open YouTube without closing my app, when I get back to my app, a full screen ad pops up)

Is there any solution to disable it?

I tried removing this Manifest code who's responsible on that ad, but my app crashes asking for that transparent activity.

```
android:name="com.startapp.sdk.adsbase.activities.OverlayActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
```

Example of the ad showing:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsqQF.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by disabling return ads.

```
StartAppSDK.init(this, "StartApp App ID", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'v tried that and It's still showing
Then I've add RETURN_ADS_DISENABLED to the meta dataand it works
so my whole meta data becames

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.startapp.sdk.APPLICATION_ID.RETURN_ADS_DISENABLED"
        android:value="ur app id" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this

```
StartAppSDK.init(this, "StartApp App ID");
StartAppAd.disableAutoInterstitial(); 
StartAppSDK.setTestAdsEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG);// this for test ad
```